# Transparent colors for mesh fill

Tags: meshlab

In MeshLab, is it possible to have transparent see-through colors for `fill` color of meshes?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

No, meshlab does not support transparency in rendering.
Despite that, if your data has values for Alpha, they are read, available to many filters as data, and stored back in the output file.

That question is explained here :
https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/161